# Creating a new post in another table changes the ID of the current post

Tags: filemaker

Using one of the finished solutions (Invoices) provided by File Maker, I took the script for creating a new customer from one layout into another. The problem I got when I implemented it is that when it creates the post to that user ID it changes the id of the older post to NULL and they don't show in that specific user portal anymore. And I cannot solve this problem:

Here is the code I'm using:
(Translated from Swedish)

Button för creating new Journal:

```
Set variable [$$CurrentPatientID ; Value: Journals::PatientID]
Set field [Journals::PatientID ; ""]
Commit Records/Requests [No dialog]
Set Script Animation [On]
Go to object [Objectname: "AddJournal_Form"]
```

Button for committing:

```
Allow user abort [Off]
If [not IsEmpty (Get(Scriptparameter)))]
Commit Records/Requests [No dialog]
Set field [Journals::PatientID ; Get (Scriptparameter)]
Close popover
Commit Records/Requests [No dialog]
Else
Commit Records/Requests [No dialog]
Go to object [Objectname: "AddJournal_Question"]
End If
```

Comment: What table occurrence was the original layout displaying from? What table occurrence is the new layout displaying from? If they're not the same, it's possible that you're updating through a relationship, which would update the first record by sort order (or the oldest record if no sort order is specified)

Comment: @pft221 I think that it goes through the relationship since the Add Journal form the table Journals is applied to the Patient Layout with Patient database. if this is what you mean

Comment: Your question is not clear - mainly because it's not clear what you *want* to do. However, I suspect this: `Set field [Journals::PatientID ; ""]` is the step that causes the problem. In any case, it doesn't make any sense to me, under any circumstances.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm sorry if it is unclear. Think that you have 2 tables, Patients and Journals. I have a layout for Patient table where I display the data. What I want to do now is that from the Patient layout create a post in the Journals table using a button in a popover.

Comment: @Montague Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

> Think that you have 2 tables, Patients and Journals. I have a layout
>   for Patient table where I display the data. What I want to do now is
>   that from the Patient layout create a post in the Journals table using
>   a button in a popover.

The scripts that you show us lead nowhere towards that goal. You should start by something like:

```
Set Variable [$patientID ; Value: Patients::PatientID]
Go to Layout [ Journals ]
New Record
Set Field [Journals::PatientID ; $patientID]
```

This assumes the two tables are related by PatientID, and that you start the script from a layout of Patients.

At the end of the above script, you will be in a layout of the Journals table, with a new record related to the original record in Patients (which presumably you will fill with some data). To return to that original record, you only need to do:

```
Go to Layout [ Patients ]
```

Comment: Michael's answer makes full sense to me, so I don't understand the someone's down-vote. Up-voting back on.